# iTunes Connect: What happens on devices when I delete an app?

Tags: ios, itunes, applications, app-store-connect

We've got an application that we're overhauling and putting a new skin on.  Marketing within our company has made the decision to cut ties with the previous application and try to market this new application instead.  Because of this, we have to delete the current application on iTunes Connect.  This I can do.  What is being asked is what kinds of ramifications are there to deleting the application?  What will happen on a customer's device that has already downloaded the app?  Obviously, if they never connect to the internet, it can continue to work as before.  But does Apple do anything special when a cert is canceled or removed or an application is deleted?  Do they wipe away the application if you try and sync the device to iTunes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter if you delete it on your developer account, the users will continue with that app until they will update or delete it. No more options here.

Answer (score 0):

When an user buy an app he become the copy owner so he own his copy on his device and ipa on iTunes and he can continue using and installing it forever as he want.
He simply stop receiving updates.